# ensure minimum functionality under heavy search load elk

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, amazon-elasticsearch

I have a 3x node elk cluster with fillowing  node characteristics:

96GB RAM

25GB heap

10x CPU

6TB total indexes size for past 30 days distributed in 1.5TB per node

the filebeat index 50GB per index split across 3x shards
~ total 100GB/day , including the 1xreplica ~ 200GB/day

The thing is that when viewing my log metrics for past 1-7 days everything is fine , but if I open dashboard to see details for past 30 days I cannot do anything else , and if I open kibana from other browser tab is throw error 408 , all CPU's are at 100%

Please, advice if there is any option to ensure single request will not take the 100% from all CPUs in all nodes and I would be able to see from second tab at least the cluster monitoring?

Thanks,

R2D2

Output from GET _cluster/stats?pretty&human

```
                {
                "_nodes" : {
                    "total" : 6,
                    "successful" : 6,
                    "failed" : 0
                },
                "cluster_name" : "elk",
                "cluster_uuid" : "CztzsocFTgmKHWI_GnqDvQ",
                "timestamp" : 1634106014829,
                "status" : "green",
                "indices" : {
                    "count" : 116,
                    "shards" : {
                    "total" : 304,
                    "primaries" : 152,
                    "replication" : 1.0,
                    "index" : {
                        "shards" : {
                        "min" : 2,
                        "max" : 6,
                        "avg" : 2.6206896551724137
                        },
                        "primaries" : {
                        "min" : 1,
                        "max" : 3,
                        "avg" : 1.3103448275862069
                        },
                        "replication" : {
                        "min" : 1.0,
                        "max" : 1.0,
                        "avg" : 1.0
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "docs" : {
                    "count" : 4672727260,
                    "deleted" : 1262101
                    },
                    "store" : {
                    "size" : "4tb",
                    "size_in_bytes" : 4490413194045,
                    "reserved" : "0b",
                    "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
                    },
                    "fielddata" : {
                    "memory_size" : "58.3mb",
                    "memory_size_in_bytes" : 61151040,
                    "evictions" : 0
                    },
                    "query_cache" : {
                    "memory_size" : "4.1gb",
                    "memory_size_in_bytes" : 4406840440,
                    "total_count" : 2390354,
                    "hit_count" : 14385,
                    "miss_count" : 2375969,
                    "cache_size" : 4760,
                    "cache_count" : 5724,
                    "evictions" : 964
                    },
                    "completion" : {
                    "size" : "0b",
                    "size_in_bytes" : 0
                    },
                    "segments" : {
                    "count" : 3404,
                    "memory" : "60.1mb",
                    "memory_in_bytes" : 63090152,
                    "terms_memory" : "29.9mb",
                    "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 31446928,
                    "stored_fields_memory" : "3.9mb",
                    "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 4122896,
                    "term_vectors_memory" : "0b",
                    "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
                    "norms_memory" : "13.8kb",
                    "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 14208,
                    "points_memory" : "0b",
                    "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
                    "doc_values_memory" : "26.2mb",
                    "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 27506120,
                    "index_writer_memory" : "59.6mb",
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 62543712,
                    "version_map_memory" : "830b",
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 830,
                    "fixed_bit_set" : "1gb",
                    "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 1168657528,
                    "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : 1634083207166,
                    "file_sizes" : { }
                    },
                    "mappings" : {
                    "field_types" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "alias",
                        "count" : 2686,
                        "index_count" : 79
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "binary",
                        "count" : 14,
                        "index_count" : 3
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "boolean",
                        "count" : 8714,
                        "index_count" : 103
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "byte",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "date",
                        "count" : 11809,
                        "index_count" : 115
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "double",
                        "count" : 2607,
                        "index_count" : 79
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "flattened",
                        "count" : 641,
                        "index_count" : 80
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "float",
                        "count" : 2611,
                        "index_count" : 88
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "geo_point",
                        "count" : 639,
                        "index_count" : 80
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "half_float",
                        "count" : 56,
                        "index_count" : 14
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "integer",
                        "count" : 186,
                        "index_count" : 11
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "ip",
                        "count" : 9888,
                        "index_count" : 80
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "keyword",
                        "count" : 285169,
                        "index_count" : 113
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "long",
                        "count" : 79464,
                        "index_count" : 109
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "nested",
                        "count" : 272,
                        "index_count" : 95
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "object",
                        "count" : 57866,
                        "index_count" : 114
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "short",
                        "count" : 7981,
                        "index_count" : 80
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "text",
                        "count" : 7837,
                        "index_count" : 104
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    "analysis" : {
                    "char_filter_types" : [ ],
                    "tokenizer_types" : [ ],
                    "filter_types" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "pattern_capture",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "analyzer_types" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "custom",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "built_in_char_filters" : [ ],
                    "built_in_tokenizers" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "uax_url_email",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "built_in_filters" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "lowercase",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "unique",
                        "count" : 1,
                        "index_count" : 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "built_in_analyzers" : [ ]
                    }
                },
                "nodes" : {
                    "count" : {
                    "total" : 6,
                    "coordinating_only" : 0,
                    "data" : 3,
                    "data_cold" : 3,
                    "data_content" : 3,
                    "data_hot" : 3,
                    "data_warm" : 3,
                    "ingest" : 3,
                    "master" : 3,
                    "ml" : 6,
                    "remote_cluster_client" : 3,
                    "transform" : 3,
                    "voting_only" : 0
                    },
                    "versions" : [
                    "7.10.2"
                    ],
                    "os" : {
                    "available_processors" : 36,
                    "allocated_processors" : 36,
                    "names" : [
                        {
                        "name" : "Linux",
                        "count" : 6
                        }
                    ],
                    "pretty_names" : [
                        {
                        "pretty_name" : "CentOS Linux 8",
                        "count" : 6
                        }
                    ],
                    "mem" : {
                        "total" : "294gb",
                        "total_in_bytes" : 315680096256,
                        "free" : "36.5gb",
                        "free_in_bytes" : 39295123456,
                        "used" : "257.4gb",
                        "used_in_bytes" : 276384972800,
                        "free_percent" : 12,
                        "used_percent" : 88
                    }
                    },
                    "process" : {
                    "cpu" : {
                        "percent" : 3
                    },
                    "open_file_descriptors" : {
                        "min" : 389,
                        "max" : 1318,
                        "avg" : 849
                    }
                    },
                    "jvm" : {
                    "max_uptime" : "4.6d",
                    "max_uptime_in_millis" : 399502750,
                    "versions" : [
                        {
                        "version" : "15.0.1",
                        "vm_name" : "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
                        "vm_version" : "15.0.1+9",
                        "vm_vendor" : "AdoptOpenJDK",
                        "bundled_jdk" : true,
                        "using_bundled_jdk" : true,
                        "count" : 6
                        }
                    ],
                    "mem" : {
                        "heap_used" : "30.9gb",
                        "heap_used_in_bytes" : 33225823136,
                        "heap_max" : "78gb",
                        "heap_max_in_bytes" : 83751862272
                    },
                    "threads" : 428
                    },
                    "fs" : {
                    "total" : "5.9tb",
                    "total_in_bytes" : 6521808826368,
                    "free" : "1.8tb",
                    "free_in_bytes" : 2028853403648,
                    "available" : "1.5tb",
                    "available_in_bytes" : 1697288646656
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ ],
                    "network_types" : {
                    "transport_types" : {
                        "security4" : 6
                    },
                    "http_types" : {
                        "security4" : 6
                    }
                    },
                    "discovery_types" : {
                    "zen" : 6
                    },
                    "packaging_types" : [
                    {
                        "flavor" : "default",
                        "type" : "docker",
                        "count" : 6
                    }
                    ],
                    "ingest" : {
                    "number_of_pipelines" : 4,
                    "processor_stats" : {
                        "conditional" : {
                        "count" : 307645168,
                        "failed" : 0,
                        "current" : 0,
                        "time" : "18.5s",
                        "time_in_millis" : 18569
                        },
                        "geoip" : {
                        "count" : 307645168,
                        "failed" : 0,
                        "current" : 0,
                        "time" : "11.3s",
                        "time_in_millis" : 11315
                        },
                        "gsub" : {
                        "count" : 0,
                        "failed" : 0,
                        "current" : 0,
                        "time" : "0s",
                        "time_in_millis" : 0
                        },
                        "rename" : {
                        "count" : 615290336,
                        "failed" : 0,
                        "current" : 0,
                        "time" : "7.1s",
                        "time_in_millis" : 7100
                        },
                        "script" : {
                        "count" : 0,
                        "failed" : 0,
                        "current" : 0,
                        "time" : "0s",
                        "time_in_millis" : 0
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
```

Output from : GET _cat/nodes?v&h=v,n,m,r,rm,du,dt,cpu,ram.percent,ram.current,heap.percent,search.query_current,heap.current,heap.total,segments.count&s=n:asc

```
 v      n                   m       r rm     du    dt    cpu  ram.percent ram.current heap.percent search.query_current heap.current segments.count
 7.10.2 elk-ingest-data-0 - cdhilrstw 96gb   1.3tb 1.9tb 100          78      74.5gb           46                    0       11.7gb           1162
 7.10.2 elk-ingest-data-1 - cdhilrstw 96gb   1.5tb 1.9tb  71          77      73.7gb           34                    0        8.6gb           1155
 7.10.2 elk-ingest-data-2 - cdhilrstw 96gb   1.5tb 1.9tb  68         100      95.9gb           52                    0         13gb           1091
 7.10.2 elk-master-0      * lm         2gb 568.3mb 9.7gb  53         100       1.9gb           37                    0      381.9mb              0
 7.10.2 elk-master-1      - lm         2gb 568.3mb 9.7gb   2          68       1.3gb           61                    0      628.9mb              0
 7.10.2 elk-master-2      - lm         2gb 568.3mb 9.7gb   3          68       1.3gb           55                    0      572.6mb              0
```

Comment: is this using the aws service? what version are you on? what is the output from the `_cluster/stats?pretty&human` API?

Comment: no , it is in-house k8s /docker , version number: "7.10.2"   , included _cluster/stats?pretty&human output to the question

Comment: thanks. yeah that cpu is quite high. what do your Elasticsearch logs show? can you upgrade to 7.15?

Comment: incresing RAM in masters , adding more shards to one of the heavy loaded indices + merging the old indices & implementing better ILM  fixed the issue ...